# The Great ELU Tag Clean-up Proposal of 2014

Tags: discussion, support, tag-synonyms, retagging

## EDIT:

So, none of this got done in 2014.  Does this mean that we should just give up on tags?  Doing almost any of these by hand will annoy people since they would all bump those questions to the top of the active list, so this requires assistance.

---

I’ve just looked through **all 856 of our tags**.   Yes, really.

I’d like to propose the following clean-up measures, some of which are trivial fixes and some of which merit further discussion.

- Change the name of [archaic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archaic) to the canonical [archaicisms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archaicisms) and make the former a tag synonym of the latter.
- Merge all of [syntactic-analysis](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntactic-analysis), [sentence-structure](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentence-structure),  and [parsing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing) with [grammatical-structure](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-structure).  The first, [syntactic-analysis](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntactic-analysis), might be preferred as the canonical version. Maybe grab [structure](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/structure) and [syntax](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax) into that, too.
- Merge and rename and syn [technical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical) and [tech-writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tech-writing) into [technical-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-language).
- Rename [concord](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concord) to [concordance](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concordance), then consider merging and synning with [agreement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agreement). We’re not talking about grapes or supersonic aircraft here.
- Merge and syn [commands](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commands) into [imperative](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imperative), and make the latter either [imperatives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imperatives) or [imperative-mood](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imperative-mood).
- Rename and syn [derivative](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivative) to [derived-terms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derived-terms). (Edit: there are no longer any posts tagged with [derivative](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/derivative).)
- Merge and syn [disjunct](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disjunct) into the existing [disjunction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disjunction). (Edit: there are no longer any posts tagged with [disjunct](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disjunct), but there are three tagged with [disjuncts](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disjuncts).)
- Merge and syn [language-change](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-change) into the existing [language-evolution](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-evolution).
- Merge and syn [movie](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie) into the exiting tag [cinema](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cinema).
- Change and syn [mood](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mood) into [grammatical-mood](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-mood).
- Merge and syn [perfect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perfect) into the existing [perfect-aspect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/perfect-aspect).
- Figure out which of [title](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/title) should be [honorifics](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/honorifics) and which should be [title-casing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/title-casing) or some such.
- Merge and syn [period](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/period) into the existing [periods](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/periods).  Well, assuming we’re talking about the [full-stop](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/full-stop) punctuation throughout rather than [historical-epochs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-epochs). (Edit: there are no longer any posts tagged with [periods](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/periods).)
- Recast the following tags  into the plural, which is generally preferred: [adjunct](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adjunct), [animal](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal), [cliche](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cliche), [complement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complement),  [conditional](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conditional), [date](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/date) (which might should be [dates-and-times](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dates-and-times) and merged with [time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time)), [demonstrative](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demonstrative), [diminutive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diminutive), [essay](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/essay) (or make it [essay-writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/essay-writing)?), [ending](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ending), [generic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generic), [irregular](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irregular), [ligature](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ligature), [list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list), [oxymoron](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oxymoron) (but maybe syn [oxymora](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oxymora) to the revised [oxymorons](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oxymorons)?), [palindrome](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palindrome), [participle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/participle),  [possessive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/possessive) (or split into [possessive-pronouns](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/possessive-pronouns) and [possessive-adjectives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/possessive-adjectives)?), [run-on-sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/run-on-sentences), [shibboleth](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shibboleth), [slogan](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slogan), [superscript](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superscript), [teaching-aid](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching-aid), [vocative](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocative).
- I’ve been doing my own burninations, but here are others that should probably go the way of all things: [concept](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concept), [construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/construction), [correction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correction), [description](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/description).
- I feel like something or other might should be done about these mixed-up tags that have been applied to completely different things, but I don’t know what: [ending](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ending) (maybe some should be [valedictions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/valedictions) to pair with [salutations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salutations)?), [feminine](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feminine), [idiomatic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiomatic), [interpretation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interpretation), [management](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/management), [participial](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/participial), [phrasing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrasing), [phase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phase), [shift](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shift), [sounds](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sounds), [tone](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tone).
- Should [philology](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philology) be merged and synned into [historical-linguistics](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-linguistics) or some such?

---

**EDIT**: See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216458), which might provide some relief to our poor overworked mods if the boon could be granted here at ELU.  People should please try to suggest and [vote on synonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest) if they can.

---

Former suggestions that have now been implemented:

- <s>Merge and syn [singular-plural](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/singular-plural) with the existing [grammatical-number](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatical-number).</s> Completed.
- <s>Merge and syn [passive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive) into the existing [passive-voice](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passive-voice).</s> Completed.
- <s>Merge and syn [places](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/places) into the existing [toponyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toponyms).</s> Completed.
- <s>Merge [short-form](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-form) into [abbreviations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abbreviations) and consider adding an [apocopation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apocopation) syn.</s> Completed.
- <s>Should [style](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/style) and [writing-style](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/writing-style) be synmerged?</s>
- <s>Make [rp](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rp) syn to [received-pronunciation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/received-pronunciation).</s> Completed.

Comment: All great suggestions! I can only add a comment to the last one. I don't know what philology is but it isn't one-to-one with historical linguistics. But if the things tagged with philology tend to be historical then I'd probably prefer to retag than synonomize.

Comment: Oh. There's only one question tagged with philology. I'd suggest just remove that tag for that one questions and delete the tag altogether.

Comment: My own preference would be to syn/merge all of [tag:present-perfect-tense], [tag:past-perfect], [tag:conditional-perfect], [tag:sp-vs-past-perfect], [tag:perfect-aspect], [tag:future-perfect], [tag:perfect] and [[tag:perfect-infinitive] into [tag:perfect-constructions]; [tag:perfect-aspect] invites confusion with [tag:perfective-aspect], and perfect constructions involve both tense and aspect.

Comment: The problem is that new users/visitor will be unaware of some the grander naming tags such as: valedictions and honorifics to name but two. Until I joined this community I had never heard of these terms. A first time visitor will write: address, salutation, greetings, or limit himself to tagging the question with "grammar" or "grammaticality". BTW what is the real difference between the two?

Comment: Another observation, many users are British and will, for example, think: *film* or *cinema* instead of *movies*. I'm not saying "movies" is unfamiliar, but it's not the first word that pops up in my head when I think of "James Bond films".

Comment: @Mari-LouA, the purpose of synonyms is precisely so that users who don't know "valedictions" and thus write "endings" in the tag box will still end up with a correctly-tagged question.

Comment: I've made all the synonym suggestions the system would allow me to. Which was a grand total of 2. I *really* wish the "synonym" link would only show up for tags if I have the necessary rep to suggest them.

Comment: @Marthaª does the "valediction" tag have a description? Many tags do not. How to tag a question, is not blindingly obvious, unless one has patience to sift through the FAQs and the help section, people will more and more tag questions with "grammar" if the simpler ones are eliminated. I'm just saying there is a case for leaving the broader tags alone. Agreed that 856 are really too many.

Comment: @Marthaª: I agree. I've suggested it on [MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216067/162511).

Comment: @StoneyB Indeed having **all eleven** of [tag:conditional-perfect], [tag:future-perfect], [tag:needs-pp], [tag:past-perfect], [tag:perfect], [tag:perfect-aspect], [tag:perfect-infinitive], [tag:pp-vs-sp], [tag:present-perfect-tense], [tag:sp-as-pp], and [tag:sp-vs-past-perfect] does seem to be getting out of hand somehow, but just where you draw the line is hard to figure out. What do you say we even the score by adding [tag:imperfect] and make it a [tag:dirty-dozen]? :)

Comment: @tchrist Well, anything that has *pp* in it should simply be rejected--is pp present perfect, past perfect, or preposition[al] phrase? ... But *conditional-perfect* should probably go to *conditionals* or *conditional-constructions*.

Comment: @StoneyB The problem is the length restrictions on the tags.

Comment: Maybe this is just my dialect, but I thought that `archaism` was more commonly used than `archaicism`.

Comment: @senshin You’re probably right.

Comment: **Related**: I would say tagging ten questions at a time would be far less annoying than retagging forty at a time. Some users have retagged "some" questions unnecessarily. When a question already has four tags, is a fifth one really indispensable? There must be moderation in all things. . .

Comment: @Mari-LouA [Tag edits](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/177070/tag-edits-by-user) happen for various different reasons, some of which are not obvious. Mass retags are generally better done *en masse* for anything more than a few dozen at a time, or else the retagger will die of boredom. If we’re going to have tags at all, then to me it makes sense to have good ones that help with searches, and any that apply should be there.

Answer (score 11):

I generally agree, and here's some suggestions, but I don't feel so strongly either way.

> - Merge and rename and syn [technical](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical) and [tech-writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tech-writing) into [technical-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-language).

I think [technical-writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing) would be better than [technical-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-language) and it's more common.

> - Change the name of [archaic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archaic) to the canonical [archaicisms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archaicisms) and make the former a tag synonym of the latter.

I'd never heard of [archaicisms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archaicisms) before and think [archaic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/archaic) will be more readily understood.

---

There's some Winter Bash tags created between December 16th and January 3rd which should be synonimsed or removed (here's the [newest tags](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new)).

I suggest at least the [rude-words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rude-words) should be made a synonym of [offensive-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offensive-language).

Comment: (Vote for the [tag:rude-words] -> [tag:offensive-language] synonym here: http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/offensive-language/synonyms)

Comment: That synonym is now in place. Any chance you could also suggest "placenames" as a synonym of "toponyms"? Apparently, I don't have the rep to do so, and I'm reluctant to cheat my way around the obstacle, artificial though it may be.

Comment: @Marthaª: Done. Vote for [places] and [placenames] -> [toponyms] [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/toponyms/synonyms).

Answer (score 4):

> - Merge and syn [movie](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie) into the exiting tag [cinema](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cinema).

I'd rather see [movie](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie) be the root and [cinema](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cinema) become the syn. I don't think most people would assume [cinema](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cinema) exists.

> - Merge and syn [places](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/places) into the existing [toponyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toponyms).

I guess this is a similar issue which really presents the greater question: Should our tags prefer "technical" words or "common" words? Most of our askers probably have no idea what a toponym is. The word doesn't even show up in a standard spellchecker. I'd rather see the root tag be [places](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/places).

But I don't feel strongly about either of these suggestions. I am much more pro-organization than I am picky about the terms used in organization.

Comment: If you want a more common alternative to *toponyms*, go for *placenames*. *Places* doesn't sound like an on-topic tag for ELU.

Comment: @Marthaª The idea is to have synsets that include both low- and high-falutin’ versions of things. Notice how [tag:spelling] auto-corrects/auto-syns to the far less commonly used [tag:orthography]. Similarly with the way [tag:singular] and [tag:plura] syn to the longer and more professional but less well-known [tag:grammatical-number]. Provided all are aliases, it in some regards doesn’t matter which becomes **ᴛʜᴇ** canonical answer. But whenever the choice as presented itself, we have selected the higher-falutin’ “more professional” term as the one to which the others are synned.

Comment: @Marthaª And so on that note, we could have [tag:movie] and [tag:movies] and [tag:film] and [tag:motion-pictures] and [tag:cinema] be the synset for one tag, of which I would myself prefer the lattermost as canonical because it sounds the most professional. But you could type anything you please. Regarding the *nym* matter, we already so very many something-*nym* tags that having [tag:toponyms] fits in well with those, no matter what its synset is (like [tag:places] and [tag:place-names]).

Comment: @tchrist: I have absolutely no problem with "toponym". My objection was to "places", which sounds like it refers to vacation destinations or some such totally off-topic subject. IOW the common/technical choice ought to be between "placenames" and "toponyms", ***not*** "places" and "toponyms".

Comment: @Marthaª Oh right, ok. That makes more sense.

Comment: I’d second all these suggestions for using the more widely-understood term as the main tag.  Another one along the same lines: [tag!singular-plural] would I think be understood by many more users than [tag!grammatical-number].