# Can trusted users propose tag-synonyms without the rep requirements?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

See [Can trusted users be trusted to suggest tag synonyms without a score of 5 in a tag? (on smaller sites, not Stack Overflow)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216080/can-trusted-users-be-trusted-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-a-t/216458#216458).

The top answer is:

> If, on a given site, there's a big problem with runaway tagging... Post a feature-request on your meta along with examples that demonstrate the need. [We've temporarily lowered this in the past for sites with a lot of cleanup to be done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69588/drop-the-score-requirement-for-proposing-tag-synonyms-atleast-for-super-user/69661#69661), and I think doing this as part of a larger, coordinated cleanup effort is a good idea. Don't forget: even after a synonym has been created, the questions involved still need to be retagged, either by individual editors, or by a moderator merging the tags.

I was going through @tchrist's [excellent list of synonym suggestions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4442/the-great-elu-tag-clean-up-proposal-of-2014) but couldn't propose most of them because I didn't have the required rep counts. Seeing that many of the tags are so infrequently used, it seems unlikely I'll get the rep any time soon.

Thus, this is a feature request to let **trusted users** submit tag synonyms. A trusted user is anyone with [20k rep or higher](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

EDIT: Since no one has responded to this feature request, can someone at least offer a suitable workaround? The above linked posts suggest that this is the appropriate thing to request.

Comment: Yes, please: let’s do this.

Comment: Not that I'm a trusted user (yet!), but could you please give a link to the list of synonym suggestions? I'd just like to take a look at them. Thanks!

Comment: @MattGutting: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4442/the-great-elu-tag-clean-up-proposal-of-2014

Comment: Appreciate it Thanks!

Comment: It'd be harder to implement, but I'd suggest something along the "vote to close" schema such that it'd take 5 "votes to synonymize" from users of sufficient rep, perhaps not necessarily as high as "trusted users," or by unilateral moderator action.

Comment: I think we’ll have to have our mods talk to the community managers about this.  But they haven’t chimed in yet.